# Quorum Tessera Implementation in Go

Tags: quorum

as Quorum and Ethereum are developed in Go, would like to understand why Tessera, the new Quorum transaction manager to replace Constellation, is written in Java instead of Go?

Thank you.

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you?

Tessera is meant as an enterprise transaction manager by which we mean the ease of setting it up within an existing large corp -- as such, its built on a well understood and supported platform that most companies support in ways that they wouldn't for something a bit more esoteric like Haskell. Additionally, Tessera utilizes various Java extensions that allow corps to set it up in such a way that a lot of tools its using is off loaded to the other enterprise tools such as logging, relational databases, hsms, and key management vaults.

Finally, by the time we have started our work on Java implementation, a Go implementation of a transaction manager was already in place by another team, please see Crux: https://github.com/blk-io/crux